# Only of Type but for 2 and 3 only types also

Tags: css

I have this problem, I'm using "only of type" for a block, the content always change sometimes there are 2 or 3 or 4 blocks.

I would like to know if there exists some code that allows me to change the css when there are just 2 or 3 like "only of type" do when there is just one.

```css
li:only-of-type {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul><li>a</li></ul>
<ul><li>a</li><li>b</li></ul>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and make it more understandable with some code

Comment: Search for "quantity queries"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use quantity queries for this purpose. They can get rather complicated though, and [builders exist](http://quantityqueries.com/) to make life easier.

```css
li:only-of-type {
  color: red;
}

li:nth-last-child(n+3):nth-last-child(-n+3):first-child, li:nth-last-child(n+3):nth-last-child(-n+3):first-child ~ li {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<ul><li>a</li></ul>
<ul><li>a</li><li>b</li></ul>
<ul><li>a</li><li>b</li><li>c</li></ul>
```